# How do I extract characters from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, pandas

I need to make some name formats match for merging later on in my script. My column 'Name' is imported from a csv and contains names like the following:

Antonio Brown

LeSean McCoy

Le'Veon Bell

For my script, I would like to get the first letter of the first name and combine it with the last name as such....

A.Brown

L.McCoy

L.Bell

Here's what I have right now that returns a NaaN every time:

`ff['AbbrName'] = ff['Name'].str.extract('([A-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)`

Thanks!

Comment: can't you use apply() to execute function which will split() it into two words, and get first char from first word plus second word.

Comment: How about `.split(' ')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option using `str.replace` method with `^([A-Z]).*?([a-zA-Z]+)$`; `^([A-Z])` captures the first letter at the beginning of the string; `([a-zA-Z]+)$` matches the last word, then reconstruct the name by adding `.` between the first captured group and second captured group:

```
df['Name'].str.replace(r'^([A-Z]).*?([a-zA-Z]+)$', r'\1.\2')
#0    A.Brown
#1    L.McCoy
#2     L.Bell
#Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is regex really necessary here?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I tend to consider regex valid here since OP is dealing with names and it's not surprising that there are unexpected formats in a real data set. `Regex` helps validate the Name as well.

Answer (score 4):

What if you would just [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function that would split by the first space and get the first character of the first word adding the rest:

```
import pandas as pd


def abbreviate(row):
    first_word, rest = row['Name'].split(" ", 1)
    return first_word[0] + ". " + rest


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Antonio Brown', 'LeSean McCoy', "Le'Veon Bell"]})
df['AbbrName'] = df.apply(abbreviate, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Name  AbbrName
0  Antonio Brown  A. Brown
1   LeSean McCoy  L. McCoy
2   Le'Veon Bell   L. Bell
```

Comment: Sometimes there might  be only firstname in the Name column right?

Comment: @Dark yeah, I guess we need to know what are the possible values for the names in the OP's particular case, but good point, we can create some inputs to break the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should be simple enough to do, even without regex. Use a combination of string splitting and concatenation.

```
df.Name.str[0] + '.' + df.Name.str.split().str[-1]

0    A.Brown
1    L.McCoy
2     L.Bell
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

If there is a possibility of the `Name` column having leading spaces, replace `df.Name.str[0]` with `df.Name.str.strip().str[0]`.

*Caveat*: Columns must have two names at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You get NaaN because your regular expression cannot match to the names.

Instead I'll try the following:

```
parts = ff[name].split(' ')
ff['AbbrName'] = parts[0][0] + '.' + parts[1]
```